# c# WPF InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, mahapps.metro

I have a error when opening a window and closing another.

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

I am using RedCorona Sockets... http://www.redcorona.com/Sockets.cs
Here is the code...

```
public partial class MainWindowThingy : Window
{
   public ClientInfo client;
    public MainWindowThingy() //The Error appears here
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartTCP();
    }
    public void StartTCP()
    {
        Socket sock = Sockets.CreateTCPSocket("localhost", 2345);
        client = new ClientInfo(sock, false); // Don't start receiving yet
        client.OnReadBytes += new ConnectionReadBytes(ReadData);
        client.BeginReceive();
    }
    void ReadData(ClientInfo ci, byte[] data, int len)
    {
        string msg = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, len));
        string[] amsg = msg.Split(' ');
        switch (amsg[0])
        {
            case "login":
                if (bool.Parse(amsg[1]) == true)
                {
                    MainWindowThingy SecondWindow = new MainWindowThingy();
                    Login FirstWindow = new Login();
                    SecondWindow.Show();
                    FirstWindow.Close(); //It starts here, the error...
                }
                else
                {
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Basicly, It gives me the error at the "Public Control()"
When closing The First Form...

Uhm... I want to open another form and close the other...  basicly

Edit:
Changed Class name...

Comment: Are you calling it from background thread?

Comment: Do not name your Window "Control". That's already a class in the .NET Framework and will only create problems further down the road.

Comment: I think so... But I dont know how to Use the dispacher on this...
can you give me a example?

Comment: @user2993512 : I have added an answer describing an issue.

Comment: Uhm... Rohits Method works... But It dosen't close FirstWindow...
Any Fixes? I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Uhm... Rohits Method works... But It dosen't close FirstWindow... Any Fixes? I dont know whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback `ReadData` is probably being called in a background thread which does not have access to the UI thread. You will need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? First get a reference to FirstWindow.Dispatcher before calling StartTCP();. After that call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, () => FirstWindow.Close());